# How to create for loop for multiple dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset, character

I have 30 datasets which are all the same, only for different companies. What I want is to do some basic tasks for all of them and it is quite demanding to repeat every command for 30 times. I thought it would be nice to create for loops. However, as I discovered, for loop cannot work with character variables. I tried to google anything or rewrite the loop as much as I could, but it did not bring any satisfying result.

I will show an example on correlation function.

```
companies<-c("a", "b", "c")
for(i in companies){
  correlations=cor(x = [i][4], y = [i][5],use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
}
```

This should create a vector of correlations of 2 different variables. I tried to use additional row of code as:

```
for(i in companies){
  e=paste(i)
  correlations=cor(x = e[4], y = e[5],use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
}
```

However nothing I have tried didn't work. Is there any trick or function, which could help? Thank you for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple error here:

**1. Lets start with the general `for`-loop structure:**

```
companies<-c("a", "b", "c")
for(i in c){
```

What should `c` be here? `c` is not defined, so **R** interprets `c` as the function `c` (see `?c`) which i am sure you dont mean.

So a for loop always needs something to loop through: a list, a vector... I guess you mean

```
companies<-c("a", "b", "c")
for(i in companies){
```

**2. How to address the data/companies**:

You try to get the data by `[i]`. This is not meaningful to **R**. Normally `[` is used for subsetting as you correctly do using `[4]` to address the fourth column. I guess what you want is to get the global variable named "a", "b" or "c" as you defined in `companies`. To do this use `get(i)`.

So assuming you have 3 variables in your global Environment (i.e. if you type `a` the data of a gets printed...) you can do this:

```
companies<-c("a", "b", "c")
for(i in companies){
  cor(x = get(i)[4], y = get(i)[5],use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
}
```

To print all of them one by one.

**3. How to save the result in a vector?**
The way you do it

```
for(i in companies){
  correlations = ...
}
```

In every iteration of the loop `correlations` gets assigned a new value. So you end up `correlations` being the correlation of the last company.

To save the results you could do something like this:

```
companies <- c("a", "b", "c")
correlations <-  vector("double", length = length(companies))
names(correlations) <- companies
for(i in companies){
  correlations[i] <- cor(...) # the above code
}
```

Now `correlations` is a named vector with all the correlations.

**>>> How to improve this?**

If you want to do the same operation on multiple same-structures objects (e.g. your companies) it is a good practice to save these objects in a list and then operate on the list objects. This can be done by:

```
dat <- mget(companies)
my_cor <- function(x){
  cor(x = x[4], y = x[5], use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
}
sapply(dat, my_cor) # gives you the list of your correlations
```

**>>> How to further improve this:**

Use the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
require(dplyr)
dat <- mget(companies)
dat <- bind_rows(dat, .id="company")
```

Now `dat` is one big data.frame containing the information of all your companies. 
    dat %>% 
      group_by(company) %>% 
      summarise(correlations = cor(VARIABLE_NAME_1, VARIABLE_NAME_2, use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")

See here for more information on the `dplyr`-Package: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html.

**P.S.:**

An Alternative to `dplyr` is `data.table`. Personally I find `dplyr` and the `tidyverse` easier to use for most tasks.

**P.P.S.:**
Excelent talk on managing multiple models using the `tidyverse`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg

Comment: To 1.: I realised that when I read the question again, but thank you for pointing that out.
To 2.: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed, I didn't know there is function like this that works for my situtation.